# Sql insert based on using already existing values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Table A(ID(Identity), col2, col3, col4)

I want to add a new entry to Table A for every ID given that col4 = '(Insert a new record for every individual in class A placing them alos in class B)'. The new record that is being
inserted has to have the same value in Col2 that it is being added and it can't be hard coded to the various entries.
Example:

```
1)1,'Michael', 'Lamboux', 'class A'(initial record)
2)2,'Sarah', 'Johanson', 'class A' (initial record)
3)...
4)...
5)...
6)1024,'Michael','Lamboux','class B'(new value)
7)1025, 'Sarah', Johanson', 'class B'(new value)
```

I am stumped on how to do due to never having done this in SQL before. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This shoould be rephrased too add `col3` :) *The new record that is being inserted has to have the same value in Col2, **Col3** that it is being added and it can't be hard coded to the various entries*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO [Table A] (col2, col3, col4)
SELECT col2, col3, 'class B' FROM [Table A]
WHERE col4='class A';
```

if it's just to add a new row for each record

**Edit**

From your comment

```
INSERT INTO tblEWF2  (E_ID,Media_ID, Min_Duration, Norm_Duration, CustDuration, Sec_ID, Task_ID, Schedule_Date, Active)
SELECT E_ID, 4845, Min_Duration, 0, CustDuration, Sec_ID, Task_ID, Schedule_Date, 1
FROM tblEWF2
```

**EDIT 2**
from your last comments ;)

```
INSERT INTO EWF2 (E_ID,Media_ID, Min_Duration, Norm_Duration, CustDuration, Sec_ID, Task_ID, Schedule_Date, Active)
SELECT E_ID,'4845',NULL, '0',NULL,'1','73',NULL,'1' 
FROM EWF2
GROUP BY E_ID
```

Comment: If I put parenthesis around the select statement Sql server gives me an error "incorrect syntax"

Comment: maybe I'm doing something wrong but every time I edit my query all it does it insert the values I want to input into every field.

Comment: Can you please clarify the problem, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: the values look like this ID, 'Michael', 'Lamboux', 'Class B' ID, 'Michael', 'Lamboux', 'Class B' ID, 'Michael', 'Lamboux', 'Class B'
It never adds anything extra to Sarah and the rest but just duplicates the same new entry for the first record.

Comment: what's the result of the select part ? (without the INSERT INTO line) ? You've got different results ?

Comment: The same results as before except all of the values that were inserted replaced the values in the previous records instead of adding an entirely new record to the DB

Comment: see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7e6e8/1 : and tell me if you have something different... Or if that's not what you want...

Comment: That is what it's supppose to do. My query looks like that but its not behaving they it is in sqlfiddle. Let me enclose the statement

Comment: Table tblEWF2 {EWF_ID(Identity), E_ID, Media_ID, Min_Duration(NULL),Norm_Duration, Cust_Duration(NULL), Sec_ID, Task_ID, Schedule_Date(NULL),Active} my statement {INSERT INTO EWF2 SELECT E_ID,'4845',NULL, '0',NULL,'1','73',NULL,'1' FROM EWF2} 
Isn't this the way it should be written?

Comment: The filter criteria was taken out. That is just to add a new row to any/all records.

Comment: @MasterP if you want to partially duplicate and change some of the values, please tell which columns should be copied and which should be changed (and to what).

Comment: The 1 in Active, the 4845 in Media_ID, the 0 in Norm_Duration, and the 1 for Sec_ID

Comment: @MasterP so see my last version, this should be fine now.

Comment: These new values have to be inserted into those new rows

Comment: If there are 6 rows with that same E_ID, will this query make 6 new rows? If so, that could be my problem.

Comment: @MasterP Oh yes of course, it will. If you want distinct E_ID, which one do you want to take, then ? You don't mind, the one with the minimal Min_Duration, other criteria ?

Comment: only one row should be added for each E_ID and each of those new rows has to have the provided values.

Comment: @MasterP but if you have two row with E_ID 1 : and Min_Duration is 3 for first row, and 4 for second row, you don't mind which one you copy ?

Comment: The Min_Duration will always be null. The Norm_duration will be set based on the Media_ID, and the Task_ID is also set off of the Media_ID 
Media_ID 4845 has Sec_ID of 1, Norm_Duration of 0, and Active of 1. Each E_ID has multiple Media_Ids assigned to it.

Comment: Looking at the results this did the trick. Now to see if I understand. The INSERT INTO puts tells the sql to insert a new record to the DB. The SELECT statement gets the information in the present row and the GROUP BY filters the E_ID's down to a single E_ID right?

Comment: @MasterP Something like that : the SELECT statement (whit the GROUP BY) get one row for each different E_ID. The other fields are "constants", so we can GROUP BY E_ID only. and we insert all these datas. Run the select statement alone, it helps to understand what's happening !

Comment: If I were to join that table with another table it would be a further filter that had extra information related to that E_ID then the SELECT and GROUP BY statements would be more constrained on the entries in which information is gathered to be inserted into right?

Comment: @MasterP Yes. Each field in the SELECT clause which is not a constant or in an Aggregate function (like MIN, MAX, COUNT...) must be in the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your column one is an identity field:

`insert into tableA (col2, col3, col4) select col2, col3, 'class B' from tableA where col4= 'class A'`

Comment: maybe I'm doing something wrong but every time I edit my query all it does it insert the values I want to input into every field

Comment: @MasterP I thought that was what you wanted. What is the difference between what this does, and what you want?

Comment: the values look like this ID, 'Michael', 'Lamboux', 'Class B' ID, 'Michael', 'Lamboux', 'Class B' ID, 'Michael', 'Lamboux', 'Class B' It never adds anything extra to Sarah and the rest but just duplicates the same new entry for the first record

Comment: So if you tried `select col2, col3, 'class B' from tableA where col4= 'class A'` without the `insert` at the front, how may rows do you see?

Comment: The same results as before except all of the values that were inserted replaced the values in the previous records instead of adding an entirely new record to the DB

Comment: I don't understand, as that is not how SQL operates. When you run an `INSERT` statement, no rows are updated, only new rows are added.